# Ratio of transversals in parallelogram

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a parallelogram. Let E is a point on BC which divides it internally in ratio p:1 and F be a point on CD which divides it internally in ratio q:1. If AF and DE meet at G, Find DG/GE and AG/GF[image]

If possible, please give the solution/hints with only geometry and without using coordinates/vectors/mass points/trigonometry, etc.

Comment: Yes, of course. You need to show only your attempts.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg It's not that I am making a mistake, I just don't know where to even start. Obviously it can be easily solved by brute forcing in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: OK. Show, how you made it and I'll show my solution. I got $\frac{1+p}{1+q+pq}$

Comment: Now I see that I got $\frac{DG}{GE}$ only,  For calculating of $\frac{AG}{GF}$ we can use the same way.

Comment: In which chapter is this homework ? Have you studied barycenters (weighted points) ?